# How can I use multiple fullScreenCover in IOS14

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I want to present the two destinations view in full screen mode from a single view.
Below is a sample of my code. Seem that the function only works for single presentation, if I have a second fullScreenCover defined, the first fullScreenCover didn't work properly.Is that any workaround at this moment?

```
import SwiftUI

struct TesFullScreen: View {
    

    
    init(game : Int){
        print(game)
    }

    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Full Screen")
    }
}
```

ContentView

```
 import SwiftUI
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @State var showFullScreen1 : Bool = false
        @State var showFullScreen2 : Bool = false
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: { self.showFullScreen1 = true }) {
                        Text("Show Full Screen 1")
                    }
                    Button(action: { self.showFullScreen2 = true }) {
                        Text("Show Full Screen 2")
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("TextBugs", displayMode: .inline)
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$showFullScreen1){
                TesFullScreen(game: 1)
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$showFullScreen2){
                TesFullScreen(game: 2)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the only thing that worked for me was from this link https://forums.swift.org/t/multiple-sheet-view-modifiers-on-the-same-view/35267 which uses the item argument instead of isPresented and you pass an optional type of enum.  This worked for me under all cases.  Using EmptyView and other approaches always broke a transition animation either to the view or when dismissing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not always the accepted answer works (for example if you have a ScrollView with subviews (cells in former days) which holds the buttons, that set the navigational flags).

But I found out, that you also can add the *fullScreen-modifier* onto an EmptyView. This code worked for me:

```
   // IMPORTANT: Has to be within a container (e.g. VStack, HStack, ZStack, ...)

   if myNavigation.flag1 || myNavigation.flag2 {

      EmptyView().fullScreenCover(isPresented: $myNavigation.flag1)
      { MailComposer() }

      EmptyView().fullScreenCover(isPresented: $myNavigation.flag2)
      { RatingStore() }
    }
```

Comment: This was working properly yet but from iOS 15 its giving the issues

Answer (score 8):

Usually some same modifier added one after another is ignored. So the simplest fix is to attach them to different views, like

```
struct FullSContentView: View {

    @State var showFullScreen1 : Bool = false
    @State var showFullScreen2 : Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: { self.showFullScreen1 = true }) {
                    Text("Show Full Screen 1")
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$showFullScreen1){
                    Text("TesFullScreen(game: 1)")
                }

                Button(action: { self.showFullScreen2 = true }) {
                    Text("Show Full Screen 2")
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$showFullScreen2){
                    Text("TesFullScreen(game: 2)")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("TextBugs", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Alternate is to have one `.fullScreenCover(item:...` modifier and show inside different views depending on input item.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that worked for me was the answer in this link:

https://forums.swift.org/t/multiple-sheet-view-modifiers-on-the-same-view/35267

Using the EmptyView method or other solutions always broke a transition animation on one of the two presentations.  Either transitioning to or from that view and depending on what order I chose them.

Using the approach by Lantua in the link which is using the item argument instead of isPresented worked in all cases:

```
enum SheetChoice: Hashable, Identifiable {
  case a, b

  var id: SheetChoice { self }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var sheetState: SheetChoice?

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ...
    }
    .sheet(item: $sheetState) { item in
      if item == .a {
        Text("A")
      } else {
        Text("B")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The sheetState needs to be optional for it to work.

Comment: This also works for me for both .fullCover and .alert presentations.  Thanks!